# load img by data

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, date

I am using this VBA code for load img (jpeg) in a excel sheet:

```
Set fPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
fPicker.Show

folderPath = fPicker.SelectedItems(1) & "\"  
pictureName = Dir(folderPath) 

Do Until pictureName = ""


Dim myPic

Set myPic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=folderPath & pictureName, linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=1, Top:=1, Width:=-1, Height:=-1)


'' Format Picture as per the requirements

myPic.Select

    Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue

    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.88, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft

    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.92, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft

    Selection.Left = pictRng.Left + 5

    Selection.Top = pictRng.Top + 5

    Selection.Width = pictRng.Width - 10

    Selection.Height = pictRng.Height - 10

    npicture = npicture + 1

pictureName = Dir
Loop
```

but this code, load the images by name.

How is it possible load the images by data?

In Microsoft documentation the dir function no shows this possibility.

Thanks

Fabio